# I am using Rake_nltk and I am trying to find which rows the output results exactly came from?

Tags: python

I am running this code and getting the attached output, is there a way I can know from which rows exactly the out came from?

```
from rake_nltk import Rake
# set the parameteres (length of keyword phrase):
r = Rake(include_repeated_phrases=False, min_length=2, 
max_length=3)
text_to_rake = data['five_gram']
r.extract_keywords_from_sentences(text_to_rake)
# filter out only the top keywords:
words_ranks = [keyword for keyword in 
r.get_ranked_phrases_with_scores() if keyword[0] > 5]
print(words_ranks)
```

[Code with output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQCNX.png)